# parent.location is not working in Firefox and Chrome but working in IE6

Tags: javascript, jsp

JSP Problem:

```
<A NAME="CustomerInformation"></A>
<table class="SectionHeader1">
    <TBODY>enter code here
        <tr>
            <td>Customer Information</td>
        </tr>
    </TBODY>
</table>
<INPUT type="button" value="Customer Details" class="buttonSuper" 
       onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)" onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)" 
       name="customerDetails" style="" 
       onclick="parent.location='#CustomerInformation'">
```

This code is working on IE6 but not working in Chrome or Firefox. Onclick I'm trying to go on same window. Could you please suggest what is problem?

Comment: I would suggest showing your code before your question gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a pop-up, thr `opener.location` instead of `parent.location`. If this is from an Iframe and the parent is on a different domain, it will not work due to the Same Origin Policy.

This is unclear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, as is your code. My interpretation was that you want a button that, when clicked, jumps to the Customer Details located on the same parent page. If that is the case, you can simplify your code. I wrote a sample that has a button element and jumps down to a Customer Information table. Some things to note:

1. You don't NEED to do input="button", just  works fine - but this code would work for  as well.
2. If you want your current window to change its location, you can use javascript: window.location = {link here}; however, in this case you can simply just add a link tag around the button element.
3. I added a  tag around your table simply to add space between the button and the table; that way, you can see a jump in the page when the button is clicked.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <a href="#CustomerInformation"><button>Customer Details</button></a>

    <div style="padding-top:2500px;">
        <A NAME="CustomerInformation"></A>
        <table class="SectionHeader1">
        <TBODY>enter code here
        <tr>
            <td>Customer Information</td>
        </tr>
        </TBODY>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have scroll bar jsp page when onclick control should go to the "CustomerInformation" section of jsp and CustomerInformation info should be selected and display in scroll bar jsp...means control should go same page of 'CustomerInformation' section of jsp.